# load testing with websockets -JMeter?

Tags: websocket, jmeter

From what I have found and tested, you can use the WebSocket Sampler for Apache JMeter, however you cannot record your test requests because the WebSocket request will not be passed appropriately through and back from the Java Proxy Server.
So, what are my options?  I can build every request by hand instead of recording - and keep using JMeter -very tedious.
Build a new WebSocket Sampler?
Build onto the Java Proxy Server?
Or use something besides JMeter?

Before I dive into another deep pit, a little good advice would be much appreciated!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think you have any good options. Unless you extend recorder / develop new recorder for web sockets. But that's a lot of work. Cheaper option (which I settled on) was to use websockets add-on for firebug (https://github.com/firebug/websocket-monitor/wiki). The rest is copy/paste (which can be partially automated using bash)

Comment: Thank you, I have installed it.  Meanwhile, I am making sure there is no way to create an ssh tunnel on Firefox using Socks5 along with the jmeter http proxy. -so far, not working